# How to show the planet always stays in the same plane?

Tags: vector-spaces, classical-mechanics

I know angular momentum $q \times p$ is conserved, where $p=L_{\dot q}$ is linear momentum.
How to apply this to a planet orbiting the star, described by the position vector $q$ relative to the star. Here $L=\frac{1}{2}M|\dot q ^2|+\frac{GM}{|q|}$.

To deduce the Kepler's law

A planet always stays in one fixed plane and the radius vector $q$ sweeps equal areas in equal time.

**My attempt:**

I compute $L_{\dot q}=M\dot q$, so the given condition means $q \times \dot q$ is conserved. I think the cross product can denote the area the planet sweeps in $\triangle t$.

But I don't know how to show the planet always stays in the same plane.

Can anyone help? Thanks very much!

Comment: Maybe transform it into polar/cylindrical coordinates and show that $\frac{dz}{d\phi} = 0$, which basically means that your z-coordinate doesn't change ?

Comment: $J = q \times p$ is a constant vector and $J \cdot q = 0$ implies $q$ lies on a plane perpendicular to $J$.

Comment: @achillehui Could you please explain why $J\cdot q=0$? Thanks!

Comment: Recall $a \cdot ( b \times c) = b \cdot ( c \times a) = c \cdot (a \times b)$, $q \cdot J = q \cdot (q \times p) = p \cdot (q \times q ) = p \cdot 0 = 0$.